# numpy - insert a two-dimensional matrix to a one-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a .npz file and I load it using numpy. So, its shape is

```
print(a.shape) 
>>> (697, )
```

For each element in it, the shape is

```
print(a[0].shape)
>>> (200,300)
```

I am wondering how I can make a new array like this. I tried defining an empty array using `b = np.empty((0, ))`, and I have another array `c` with the shape `(200,300)`. I tried to insert this 2D array at the first position of `b`. So, the expected shape of `b` should be `(1, )`, and I can get the shape of `(200,300)` when I do `print(b[0].shape)`.

I did `b = np.insert(b, 0, c, axis=0)` and there was an error `could not broadcast input array from shape (200,300) into shape (200,)`

Comment: you can't change a (0,) shape into a (1,) by 'inserting'.  Check the `dtype` of the loaded array.  Compare that with the one made by `np.empty`.  You don't understand arrays shape and dtype well enough to attempt these games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting, `could not broadcast input array from shape (200,300) into shape (200,)` comes from a mismatch in the shapes of the arrays that you're trying to insert.

In `numpy`, the smaller array is "broadcast" across the larger array, so they have compatible shapes.

However, `numpy` can only broadcast arrays together if their dimensions meet certain conditions. You will get a `"could not broadcast"` error if these conditions are not met. For example, numpy can "stretch" a one-dimensional array to fill a two-dimensional array as long as the lengths of the relevant dimensions match.

But in your case, you're trying to insert a two-dimensional array of shapes `(200,300)` into a one-dimensional array of shape `(0,)` - which means the array `b` is currently empty. There's no valid way for numpy to "stretch" or "shrink" the two-dimensional array to make it fit in the one-dimensional array, so it throws an error.

The solution is to ensure that the array you're inserting into `b` has the right shape. If you know that `b` will contain arrays of shape `(200,300)`, you should initialise `b` with shape `(0, 200, 300)`, This will allow `numpy` to insert new arrays along the first dimension of `b` properly.

```
b = np.zeros((0,200,300))
c = np.zeros((200,300))

# Adding new axis to array c for correct concatenation
c = c[np.newaxis, :] 

# Concatenating along the first axis (axis=0)
b = np.concatenate((b, c), axis=0)

print(b.shape)  # Outputs: (1,200,300)
print(b[0].shape)  # Outputs: (200,300)
```

**So far, we have only talked about homogeneous arrays (i.e., all elements of the same type).**

Although `numpy` is mainly used with homogeneous arrays for speed and memory efficiency and optimisations possibility (e.g. vectorisation), it is possible to have a 1D array of objects where each object is a 2D numpy array. It might be beneficial in some situations, e.g. when those 2D arrays have different dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize an empty array of objects
a = np.empty((697,), dtype=np.object)

# Fill the array with 2D arrays
for i in range(697):
    a[i] = np.zeros((200, 300))

# Verify the shapes
print(a.shape)  # Outputs: (697,)
print(a[0].shape)  # Outputs: (200,300)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I think the key step here is to set `dtype=object`, and this works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Define `b` as a 'empty' list

```
b = []
for i in range(3):
    b.append(np.ones((10,20)))
print(b)
```

If you really must have an array

```
arr = np.array(b)
print(arg.shape)
```

Your original loaded array probably has an `object` dtype.  As such, it basically list.  Verify that!

It is possible to make object dtype arrays, but construction is usually awkward, and should be avoided if you don't really need it.

Do not try to immitate lists with arrays.  Learn to use arrays as they are intended, with numeric dtypes.

### edit

`np.insert` is complicated function, intended to work with compatible shaped numeric arrays.  It can be used, sort of, but:

Make an 'empty' but object dtype:

```
In [33]: b=np.empty(0, object)
In [34]: b
Out[34]: array([], dtype=object)
```

Inserting a scalar works ok - still object dtype:

```
In [35]: np.insert(b,0,3)
Out[35]: array([3], dtype=object)
```

Trying to insert an array, runs into the broadcasting issue you encountered - even when its object dtype.

```
In [36]: np.insert(b,0,np.ones((2,3)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 1
----> 1 np.insert(b,0,np.ones((2,3)))

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in insert(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:5406, in insert(arr, obj, values, axis)
   5404 new[tuple(slobj)] = arr[tuple(slobj)]
   5405 slobj[axis] = slice(index, index+numnew)
-> 5406 new[tuple(slobj)] = values
   5407 slobj[axis] = slice(index+numnew, None)
   5408 slobj2 = [slice(None)] * ndim

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2,)
```

Inserting a dict, even if contains an array is ok:

```
In [37]: np.insert(b,0,{'c':np.ones((3,2))})
Out[37]:
array([{'c': array([[1., 1.],
              [1., 1.],
              [1., 1.]])}    ], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your method also works, but I don't want to insert a dict into the array. But setting `dtype=object` is necessary here.